# Command that searches in arrays | problem with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js, command

Hey I want to make a command to search in arrays on an http request and get the value I want due to what day I call in command.

For example: !day Monday, prints: Nutrition for mondey: {the array content}

*The link for the http request will be like that: "http://IP:PORT/nutrition.json"

Here is the list that the http request will print in the link:

```
             [
                
                {
                    "Day":"Monday",
                    "id":1,
                    "Nutrition":[
                        "apple",
                        "banana",
                        "spaghetti",
                        "buritto",
                    ],
                    "name":"George",
                    "lastName": "Brown"
                },

                {
                    "Day":"Tuesday",
                    "id":2,
                    "Nutrition":[
                        "apple",
                        "banana",
                        "spaghetti",
                        "buritto",
                    ],
                    "name":"George",
                    "lastName": "Brown"
                },

            ]
```

And here is the code:

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
        
        let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

        
        if (message.content.startsWith("!day")) {
            

            const list = [
                
                {
                    "Day":"Monday",
                    "id":1,
                    "Nutrition":[
                        "apple",
                        "banana",
                        "spaghetti",
                        "buritto",
                    ],
                    "name":"George",
                    "lastName": "Brown"
                },

                {
                    "Day":"Tuesday",
                    "id":2,
                    "Nutrition":[
                        "apple",
                        "banana",
                        "spaghetti",
                        "buritto",
                    ],
                    "name":"George",
                    "lastName": "Brown"
                },

            ]


            const DAY = args[1]
        

            
            request.get("http://IP:PORT/nutrition.json", function(err, response, body, text){
                
            
                if (body.includes(args[1])) {

                   
                    
                    
                        // SEARCH THE ARRAYS IN THE BODY OF THE HTTP REQUEST

                    
                    

                } else {
                    message.channel.send("`❌` There is no day with specific nutrition.")
                }


            })
            
                


            


            

            
        }



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you almost get the right code.

```
const DAY = args[1]    
var found = list.find(function(elem) {
              if(elem.day == DAY) {
                return elem.nutrition
              }
             })
if (!found) {
  message.channel.send("`❌` There is no day with a specified nutrition.")
} else {
 // DO WHAT EVER YOU NEED TO DO WITH YOUR NUTRITION OBJECT
}
```

Comment: Hey your answer was very usefull but what if i upload them in a vps and have to http there like: http://IP:PORT/nutrition.json ... i am trying to do it by your way but it prints body.find is not a function... thnx again :)